# Cargar datos en el nav_header con informacion de MYSQL en Android Studio

Tags: mysql, android-studio

El problema es que intento recuperar datos de una BD Mysql y ponerlos en el nav_header de la lista de opciones. La recuperación de indormación desde la base de datos funciona bien, pero no logro llevar esos datos a los campos tvNombreEl, tvNombreElla y tvNombrePareja.

Los metodos utilizando volley devuelven la información correcta y son almacenados en las variables el, ella y par. Pero no setean los campos de los textview.

Haciendo un debug, tambien encuentro que en el método onResponse, la información si esta correctamente puesta en las variables.

```
public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
        InicioFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        AmigosFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        BuscarFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        PerfilFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        DisponiblesFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        MensajesFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        EventosFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        ClubesFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        ConfigFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Response.ErrorListener,
        Response.Listener<JSONObject>{

    public TextView tvNombreElla, tvNombreEl, tvNombrePareja;
    ProgressDialog progreso;
    Context context = this;
    public String ella = "";
    public String el = "";
    public String par = "variable en cero";

    RequestQueue request;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        request= Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext());
        progreso = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progreso.setMessage("Entrando a SeetPar...");
        progreso.show();
        cargarWebService();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        Fragment fragmentoDefault = new InicioFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_principal, fragmentoDefault).commit();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

        ////////////////////// PERSONALIZAR ENCABEZADO //////////////////////////

        View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        TextView tvNombreElla = hView.findViewById(R.id.tvNombreElla);
        TextView tvNombreEl = hView.findViewById(R.id.tvNombreEl);
        TextView tvNombrePareja = hView.findViewById(R.id.tvNombrePareja);

        tvNombreEl.setText(el);
        tvNombreElla.setText(ella);
        tvNombrePareja.setText(par);
        Log.e("Pruebas",""+el);
        tvNombreEl.setText("Prueba");
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------

    }

    public void cargarWebService() {

        Archivos login = new Archivos();
        String nombreArchivo = context.getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/filelogin.sp";
        String nombreUsuario = login.leerArchivo(nombreArchivo);
        String url = "https://sweetpar.000webhostapp.com/webservices/consultar1.php?etUsuario="+nombreUsuario;
        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,null,this,this);
        request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        Toast.makeText(context,"No se pudo ingresar"+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progreso.hide();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response)  {

        Toast.makeText(context,"Mensaje JSON: "+response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("JSON",""+response);

        Usuario miUsuario = new Usuario();

        JSONArray json = response.optJSONArray("pareja");
        JSONObject jsonObject=null;

        try {
            jsonObject=json.getJSONObject(0);
            miUsuario.setId_usuario(jsonObject.optString("id_usuario"));
            miUsuario.setNick_ella(jsonObject.optString("nick_ella"));
            miUsuario.setNick_el(jsonObject.optString("nick_el"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        par = miUsuario.getId_usuario();
        el = miUsuario.getNick_el();
        ella = miUsuario.getNick_ella();
        progreso.hide();
    }
```

Comment: Comenta esta línea a ver si se ve el texto: `navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);` ¿Esto tampoco se muestra: `tvNombreEl.setText("Prueba");`? Conviene que pongas el XML de tu `NavigationView` y donde están los `TextView` pulsando en [edit]

Comment: Gracias, solo quito la tinta para que mis iconos personalizados se vean en color. El texto"Prueba si se visualiza, pero no cuando lo hago a través de las variables.

Comment: ¿Pero dices que las variables `el` y `ella` sí se muestran en el Log?

Comment: No, solo se muestran en el log cuando hago debug al final de todos los procesos pero no logro traer los valores a los textview

Comment: Haz las asignaciones dentro del `try` . ¿El log de `response` se muestra? ¿Puedes agregar a la pregunta lo que trae la petición? En muchos casos hay confusión con respecto al tipo de respuesta.

Comment: Lo hice y nada. esto es lo que retorna el JSON: "E/JSON: {"pareja":[{"0":"SweetPar2","id_usuario":"SweetPar2","1":"Gloria","nick_ella":"Gloria","2":"Freddy","nick_el":"Freddy"}]}"

Comment: La respuesta llega entonces. Pero estas asignaciones debes hacerlas dentro del `try` también, no fuera de él: `par = miUsuario.getId_usuario();
        el = miUsuario.getNick_el();
        ella = miUsuario.getNick_ella();`

Comment: Si aún así no funciona, puede que sea debido a que Volley es asíncrono y por tanto debes hacer las asignaciones a los textView  dentro del `onReponse` de Volley o llamar desde ahí a otro método pasándole los datos y hacer las asignaciones en ese método (tendrías entonces que crear las referencias a los textView en el método donde los vas a setear. [Mira esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/259504/29967) con un caso parecido. Lo resolví haciendo como te digo. El problema es que al ser asíncrono el dato sigue siendo nulo si intentas usarlo en el `onCreta` seguido de la llamada Volley.

Comment: Puse los llamados dentro del TRY y efectivamente todo funciono. Muchas gracias!!!