# Como modificar variable global con parametro recibido de clase interna en Android

Tags: android

Tengo una variable GLOBAL  String cadena;
y tengo unos valores recibidos en una clase interna que es el siguiente:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RequestQueue queue;



ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

ArrayList<String> lis;

 String cadena="";






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        //text1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        lista=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        lis=new ArrayList<String>();


      hacer();

       // Toast.makeText(this,Integer.toString(jsons.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       // adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,lis);

        //lista.setAdapter(adapter);

    }








    public void hacer(){



    queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        String url="";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        cadena=Integer.toString(response.length());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

        Toast.makeText(this, cadena, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }





}
```

pero no funciona porque supuestamente no se puede modificar una variable de clase externa en una clase interna. Entonces que puedo hacer para obtener ese response en una variable y usarla en el onCreate ??? Lo que quiero es sacar el response del metodo onResponse y utilizarlo en el onCreate. Pero el metodo "hacer" no me permite guardar el response del metodo onResponse en una variable fuera del metodo y no se porque

Acabo de editar el metodo :

```
public void hacer(){



    queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        String url="https://androidfe.herokuapp.com/items";
try{

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    if(response!=null){
                        cadena="viene con algo";
                    }
                    else{
                        cadena="viene vacio";
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    text1.setText(error.getMessage());
                }
            });

    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}catch (Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}



        Toast.makeText(this, cadena, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
```

Al final me imprime un Toast nulo, sin nada. No cae en ningun catch ni nada solo imprime nulo

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93025/discussion-on-question-by-richard-viquez-perez-como-modificar-variable-global-co).

Answer (score 2):

He hecho una prueba directa con la petición de tu URL.

El motivo por el que `cadena` era siempre `null` es porque la llamada a Volley es asíncrona y el dato no puede ser recuperado en el `onCreate`.

Vamos a seguir el siguiente procedimiento y verás que sí funciona:

- Desde el `onCreate` llamamos a `hacer()`, método que lanza la petición Volley
- En `hacer()` leeremos la respuesta y la concatenaremos en un `StringBuilder` (es mucho mejor que una simple cadena). **Nótese** que en la clase hay un nuevo miembro `sb`. Lo usaremos también para capturar un posible error.
- Desde dentro de `hacer()`, cuando hayamos terminado, llamaremos a un nuevo método `show`, que mostrará el resultado de la petición (éxito o error) en el `TextView`. **Nótese** que para tener acceso al `TextView` dentro del método `show()` éste tiene que ser declarado como miembro de la clase, no dentro del método `onCreate`. Y lo vamos a inicializar también dentro del método `show`, que será el dedicado de actualizar el contenido del `TextView`.

El código quedaría entonces así:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RequestQueue queue;
    private StringBuilder sb;
    TextView mTextView;

    //Otras variables ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Otras cosas. RECUERDA no inicializar el textview aquí
        hacer();
    }

    public void hacer() {
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url="https://androidfe.herokuapp.com/items";
        sb=new StringBuilder();
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject(0);
                            for (int i=0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject mItem = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                sb.append("Código: ");
                                sb.append(mItem.getString("Codigo"));
                                sb.append("\nPrecio: ");
                                sb.append(mItem.getInt("Precio"));
                                sb.append("\nCantidad: ");
                                sb.append(mItem.getString("Cantidad"));
                                sb.append("\nCategoria: ");
                                sb.append(mItem.getString("Categoria"));
                                sb.append("\nCosto: ");
                                sb.append(mItem.getInt("Costo"));
                                sb.append("\nImpuesto: ");
                                sb.append(mItem.getString("Impuesto"));
                                sb.append("\n\n");
                            }
                            show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            sb.append(e.getMessage());
                            show();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        sb.append("La petición falló. Error: "+error.getMessage());
                        show();
                    }
                }
        );

        queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }


    private void show() {
        mTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mTextView.setText(sb.toString());
    }

}
```

He probado este código en un Activity y me funciona perfectamente. Aquí te dejo una captura de pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tienes algún problema o error lo dices en comentarios. Espero te sirva.

Comment: NO funciono. Intente imprimir cadena fuera del metodo hacer

Comment: Es decir si cayera en un catch la cadena agarraria el valor del error pero se imprime null , nisiquiera cae en un catch

Comment: Por favor intente imprimir el valor de cadena en el onCreate

Comment: Declara la variable así: `private String cadena;` he hecho esto mil veces y me funciona. Si no te funciona es porque algo tienes mal en tu código.

Comment: A usted le funciona?? Yo tengo el codigo que usted me mando y no funciona???

Comment: Voy a crear un nuevo proyecto a ver si es algo de referencias o algo

Comment: D e cualquier manera gracias

Comment: @RichardVíquezPérez revisa la respuesta editada y las explicaciones. Al final, una captura de la prueba contextual. Saludos.

Comment: AHORA SI FUNCIONO. MIL GRACIAS!!!!